# Product Imports using ho-nl/Ho_Import not displaying in frontpage until I choose an additional category and save

Tags: catalog, importexport, avs-fastsimpleimport

Im working with Catalog_Product Import using extension [ho-nl/Ho_Import](https://github.com/ho-nl/Ho_Import). My current import procedure place the product with a checkbox in its category as you can see on the image.

[image: sin titulo]

But the problem is that the product is not displayed until I go to categories and select another one like Root Catalog and save again the product.

In that moment the product appears in the frontend. Is this a code problem or do I need to setup additional information on the lightweight module?. my current info for category is:

<_category field="_category" />

and in import options:

```
        <import_options>
            <partial_indexing>1</partial_indexing>
```

any help appreciated.

Comment: If you haven't done so already, I'd ask the question at the GitHub page of Ho_Import (https://github.com/ho-nl/Ho_Import/issues).

Comment: @AndreasvonStudnitz https://github.com/ho-nl/Ho_Import/issues/104 I already asked but I only solve one part of the question. Currently I have a category selection but is not displayed in frontend until i save it again. products are only save in the category, but not in the category path. weird.